# How to self host an asmx web service at runtime?

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, asmx, functional-testing

I have a web service I need to make some unit/functional test for. Since these tests should be self contained, I cannot manually host this service on my local IIS: ideally the tests should start and host the service when they are run. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Extract the business logic from the service and test that. Also, don't use ASMX for new development. Use WCF or WebAPI.

Comment: I cannot do either: if I extract the business logic, the data returned has a different format (namespace/serialization) than what is returned from the webservice in the Production server. And I have to use asmx because this is application maintenance

Comment: You can move the business logic like CodeCrasher said to its own service and return a custom response type then map that into you asmx response.

Comment: I had no luck doing this. Instead, I decided to run IIS Express from the command line (PS) `& 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe' /path:d:\SoapSandbox\Service\ /port:62455` and keep it running during the development or CI run. In my case, it is stateless, so tests will not affect it.